# How do we get syntax highlighted python in this stack exchange?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, formatting

maybe im missing something.. but this should show some colours at the very least.
(insert some generic python here)

```
for i in range(40):
    print("something")
```

I understand that the syntax highlighting isn't a big deal for some people, but having to run a plugin in my browser to highlight code on sites doesn't sit well with me. If we can have these kbd tags, there is no acceptable reason to not have decent basic syntax highlighting. (unless that would require the parser to import bpy.. )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the email from [iKlsR](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12/iklsr) regarding this request.

I have now enabled highlighting of code section by default - using the default of python.

From the few posts I have looked at that do have python, it looks good. Let me know if there are any issues with this.

Comment: cool, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It should work, by adding `<!-- language: lang-py -->` at the top but oddly it doesn't seem to work here..

```
def __init__(self):
    pass
```

Comment: OK, if the beta grows this has a chance of happening? :)

Comment: @zeffii see my comment on the question, based upon what I have learnt, it is enabled upon request, so quite possibly yes.

Comment: then whose door do we knock on for this?

Comment: @zeffii I am thinking of emailing one of the SE mods or waiting till they see this.